# java 8 and selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, java-8

Got a question for ya guys. I am trying to use streams and automation with Selenium.
I got `List<WebElement> getAllButtons;` //in this list I got around 5 buttons

```
getAllEditButtons().stream()
  .limit(2).forEach(webElement -> {
        webElement.click();
        PageUtil.clearInputAndSendKeys(userPassword, password);
        PageUtil.clearInputAndSendKeys(userReEnterPassword, password);
        saveClient.click();
    });
```

After first iteration in forEach I got :

`"org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"`

Any ideas how to fix this instead of rewrite in simple code)

Comment: I don't understand lamda expressions, o/w I could've helped you

Comment: you need to re-identify List element in each iteration, because some action is making that element to load again

Comment: you can get the element locator details such as xpath from the stream and  construct your webelement to avaoid stale.

Comment: You try with simple for loop and reidentify list as kunal said

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your edit buttons are recreated after of the first click in your loop.

Therefore, the web elements returned by `getAllEditButtons()` would no longer exists in the second iteration.

To overcome this issue, you'll have to find the web elements again:

```
IntStream.range(0, getAllEditButtons().size())
  .limit(2)
  .forEach(i ->
    getAllEditButtons()[i].click();
    ...
  );
```